# Python : How to match only one of the words using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
regular_expression = re.compile(r'SKIPPED|PASSED|FAILED')
regular_expression.search(line)
```

The above regular expression will selected all the lines that have one of the  words(SKIPPED|PASSED|FAILED)

Problem is : It selects the below line also

```
TYPE   TOTAL   SKIPPED      PASSED    FAILED
----   -----   -------      ------    ------

Module   21      0            19        3
```

So is their a way so that it selects line only if one of the three words are present ?

Comment: It is really easier without a regex. Look at [`^(?:(?!SKIPPED|PASSED|FAILED).)*(?:SKIPPED|PASSED|FAILED)(?!.*(?:SKIPPED|PASSED|FAILED))`](https://regex101.com/r/oo2kOi/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Clever golf with the lookbehind there. Gets a +1 from me.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz: The *lookahead* in the expression is a part of the so called [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

Answer (score 1):

Nobody sane would recommend doing this with a regex in production code, but for the sake of completeness, here's an answer using [positive and negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?:(?=.*PASSED)(?!.*(?:FAILED|SKIPPED))|(?=.*FAILED)(?!.*(?:PASSED|SKIPPED))|(?=.*SKIPPED)(?!.*(?:FAILED|PASSED)))
```

Basically, what it'll do is look ahead to ensure that the string contains any one of the words that you want, then look ahead again to make sure it doesn't contain either of the other two.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/14P8TD/1)

Answer (score 1):

how about using `re.findall` instead and check for only 1 item match, match only True when `re.findall` return only single match item

```
regular_expression = re.compile(r'SKIPPED|PASSED|FAILED')
match = len(regular_expression.findall(line)) == 1
```